# Getting an error when trying to install pyaardvark

Tags: python, pip

I am using the canopy distribution of python (version 2.7.6) on win8-64, and when trying to use pip to install the module `pyaardvark`, I get the following error:

```
!pip install pyaardvark
Collecting pyaardvark
Using cached pyaardvark-0.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "c:\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-5tvubw\pyaardvark\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).rstrip()
  File "c:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```